# How to untangle/undo a merge over applied MQ patches?

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging, mercurial-queue

I accidentally merged a branch into a workspace with applied patches.

How do I clean up this mess? Do I have to clean the merge (`hg up -C`) or is there some way to save my merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Mercurial 1.9.1, TortoiseHg 2.1.2*

I reproduced the basis of the situation with these commands on a fresh repo:

```
echo first > file.txt
hg add
hg ci -m first
hg branch test
echo test1 >> file.txt
hg ci -m test1
hg up 0
echo patch >> file.txt
hg qnew -f patch.diff
```

Then I performed `hg merge test` and resolved conflicts, and tried some different things:

- Committing is denied due to the involvement of patches:

  ```
  abort: cannot commit over an applied mq patch
  ```
- I could not shelve the merge in TortoiseHg.
- I could not `qnew`:

  ```
  abort: cannot manage merge changesets
  ```

The only thing I found I could do to keep the merge was to finish the patches and commit the merge changeset. With the givens, I think keeping the patches and keeping the merge are mutually exclusive.

I know that [pbranch](http://arrenbrecht.ch/mercurial/pbranch/simple.htm) allows merging with patches, and there's probably some way to import your MQ patches into it. I don't think it's supported in TortoiseHg, though.